# Addition theorem of probability

Tags: probability

A person keeps throwing a die until he gets a 6. Find the probability that every number appears atleast once before getting a six

Comment: What have you done so far? And what's that "addition theorem" you are referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Alternative 1 (tedious)

Define $A_{i}$ as “$i$ does not appear before $6$ appear on the $n$-th throw”.

$$
\begin{aligned}
P(A_{i})&=\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)\\
P(A_{i}\cap A_{j})&= \left(\frac{3}{6}\right)^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)\\
P(A_{i}\cap A_{j}\cap A_{k})&= \left(\frac{2}{6}\right)^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)\\
P(A_{i}\cap A_{j}\cap A_{k}\cap A_{l})&= \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)\\
P(A_{i}\cap A_{j}\cap A_{k}\cap A_{l}\cap A_{m})&= \left(\frac{0}{6}\right)^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

We now use the principle of inclusion - exclusion to obtain probability of at least one number does not appear before $6$ on the $n$-th throw.

$$
\begin{aligned}
P(A_{1}\cup A_{2}\cup A_{3}\cup A_{4}\cup A_{5})&=\binom{5}{1}\frac{4^{n-1}}{6^{n}}-\binom{5}{2}\frac{3^{n-1}}{6^{n}}+\binom{5}{3}\frac{2^{n-1}}{6^{n}}-\binom{5}{4}\frac{1^{n-1}}{6^{n}}+\binom{5}{5}\frac{0^{n-1}}{6^{n}}
\end{aligned}
$$

The probability of all number appear at least once before $6$ is

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(1-P(A_{1}\cup A_{2}\cup A_{3}\cup A_{4}\cup A_{5}))}&=1-\left(5\times\frac{1}{2}-10\times\frac{1}{3}+10\times\frac{1}{4}-5\times\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{6}
\end{aligned}
$$

What an anti - climax...

## Alternative 2 (short)

We throw the dice until all numbers appear at least once. This way, the number that appear last, only appear once. The probability of that number being $6$ is $\frac{1}{6}.$

Answer (score 0):

By symmetry, every number has the same probability to appear last. Thus the probability that $6$ appears last is $\frac16$.

Comment: Wow – two downvotes, no upvotes – would anyone care to comment? From the other answer it seems that I didn't misunderstand the question – what's the problem?

Comment: too little discussion/explanation (I didn't downwote).